# Counting the integer soultions to this parametric inequality

Tags: diophantine-equations, parametric

hello I am looking for an efficient way, hopefully a formula or a somewhat tight upper bound, for the number of integer solutions to the following

let $k$ be a fixed integer and $\lambda \ge 1$ and $n>m>0$.  I wish to know how many choices there are for triples, $(\lambda,n,m)$ that satisfy:

$k \ge \lambda(n^2+m^2)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: So $\lambda$ is variable.  Is it restricted to positive integers? If so this is not far from the Gauss circle problem. I have not figured out whether to what degree the multiple counting of lattice points messes up the asymptotics.

Comment: Yes, lambda is variable and restricted to positive integers.  I saw your comment a minute ago but it appears you are unsure about your answer now.  Let me know if you come up with anything.  I would be happy with any reasonable upper bound, though a lower bound would not help me

Comment: If $\lambda$ is fixed at $1$, the number is asymptotically $\frac{\pi k}{8}$.

Comment: i looked at the wikipedia page for the gauss circle problem, seems like we could just apply the same technique to circles of a different radius corresponding to different $\lambda$ and then add these and account for repeats as much as possible

Comment: Yes, we can. The asymptotics do get messed up, What kind of upper bound would be satisfactory?

Comment: anything less then $k^2$ would be sufficent

Comment: No  problem, it is a lot less.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is large and $\lambda=1$  it is approximately $\frac {\pi k}8$  If $\lambda=2$ it is $\frac {\pi k}{8 \cdot 2}$  If we cut this off at $\lambda=k$ we get a total of $\frac {\pi k}8 H_k$, where $H_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ [Harmonic number.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)  This is approximately $\frac {\pi k}8 (\log k + \gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, about $0.577$